# Core Java Faces - 3rd edition (Cay Horstmann) : Chapter 4 selection tags pg 165 example not working

Tags: jsf

I'm not sure how i should put this question cos' there are couple of files (.java, .xhtml, etc) involved. Anyway this programs involves couple of checkboxes (selectmanycheckbox) and others. There is a onchange=submit() on this selectmanycheckboxes.

Here's what i noticed:

1. The generated html for each of those checkboxes there is a onchange=submit(). Kind of funny that by checking a checkboxes, it is submitting the form everytime.

The real issue is when i check one of the checkboxes, there is an error exactly as printed.

======================================================================
java.lang.ClassCastException: [I cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

Caused by:
java.lang.ClassCastException - [I cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

I don't understand the [I here. Any idea?

What i did after that was to remove all the checkboxes and submit the form. Still getting the same error.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [source code](http://horstmann.com/corejsf/corejsf3-examples.zip) is available on [their site](http://horstmann.com/corejsf/). Your particular code is provided in `javaee/ch04/select` folder.

> *The generated html for each of those checkboxes there is a onchange=submit(). Kind of funny that by checking a checkboxes, it is submitting the form everytime.*

It's been set by the `<h:selectManyCheckbox onchange="submit()" />` in the code example. The `onchange` attribute is indeed totally unnecessary. It's likely an oversight of the author.

---

> *The real issue is when i check one of the checkboxes, there is an error exactly as printed.*
>
> ```
> java.lang.ClassCastException: [I cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
> ```
>
> *I don't understand the [I here. Any idea?*

The `[I` is the signature of an `int[]` type. The exception is telling that an instance of `int[]` type cannot be cast to an instance of `Object[]`. This makes in turn no sense, it should work fine. This particular problem is caused by something else.

---

> *What i did after that was to remove all the checkboxes and submit the form. Still getting the same error.*

The `<h:selectManyMenu>` in the code example is also bound to an `int[]` property.

However removing them is not the right solution. It should work fine. Your problem is caused by something else deeper under the hoods. It's likely a bug in the EL implementation used. What servletcontainer make/version are you using? What servlet API version is your `web.xml` declared to? Did you try upgrading the servletcontainer?

Comment: @BalusC Here's what i'm using: a. Eclipse Indigo b. apache tomcat 7.0.11 c. myfaces 2.0.5. By the way, in this book there is a javaee and tomcat version. I'm using the tomcat version.

Comment: I ran the example without trouble using Mojarra 2.0.4 on Tomcat 7.0.11. Don't you have any servletcontainer specific `el-*.jar` files in your `/WEB-INF/lib`? (if you have, remove them, they don't belong there)

Comment: @BalusC Nothing on /WEB-INF/lib .. :O( Could it be the myfaces 2.0.5 bug?

Comment: Could be. I don't use MyFaces, so I can't confirm that. Mojarra 2.0.4 is available [here](http://java.net/projects/javaserverfaces/downloads/download/release%252Fmojarra-2.0.4-FCS-binary.zip). It should be a matter of replacing the two `jsf-*.jar` files in `/WEB-INF/lib` and if necessary removing any MyFaces related params/settings in `web.xml`.

Comment: @BalusC i downloaded mojara2.1.1 and i put the jar file in the classpath to use it. Problem is when i start tomcat .. lots of error messages.

Comment: 2.1.1 has annotation scanning issues with Tomcat 7. This is a known issue and they are working on that. Hence use 2.0.x when you're on Tomcat 7. Or replace Tomcat by Glassfish. I've ever written a tutorial for that, you may find it useful as well http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html

Comment: @BalusC Thanks. I will take a look at your blog. Anyway i tried with Mojarra 2.0.4 and it works. I guess it's always better stick to Sun/Oracle

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to run the example on Tomcat 6

Your WEB-INF/lib folder should have only these files: jsf-api.jar, jsf-impl.jar. You can download them from http://javaserverfaces.dev.java.net/

On your Tomcat/lib folder, you should replace the file el-api.jar by the file el-api2.2.jar. You can download it from http://download.java.net/maven/2/javax/el/el-api/2.2/